# Add popup menu to Eclipse Problems view

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I wish to add a popup menu to the Eclipse Problem View. I can add the menu but I want it to only appear under certain condition. Like for example when a certain type of problem is selected in the problems view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the "org.eclipse.ui.menus" extension point and the command framework, you can set the [visibleWhen](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions#) part of the menu definition to something like;

```
 <visibleWhen>
    <with variable="selection">
      <iterate>
        <and>
          <instanceof value="com.example.MyClass">
          </instanceof>
        </and>
      </iterate>
    </with>
  </visibleWhen>
```

This should only make the option visible when the selected items are of the correct instance.
It is also possible to set enabled and active states on command handlers in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks that worked great. One final sub-question of this. Can I for instance narrow it down by one of the values in the table? Say the type?

Comment: It sounds like you need to investigate [property testers](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Command_Core_Expressions#Property_Testers) for this more detailed type of check. Eclipse provides some default ones, but you can also implement your own.